# Rendering md from quarto in Github

Tags: github, r-markdown, rstudio, github-flavored-markdown, quarto

I have a markdown created using the (new) RStudio quarto engine. I want to upload the .md in a Github repo. However, few elements render properly. For instance, many tables do not render, some markdown code renders as is (e.g. `:::{.column-page}`).

This is my first time using quarto. If I want to create an r markdown that is as compatible with Github markdown engine as possible, what should I do (I don't have to stick with quarto)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Quarto to convert your input to GitHub Flavored Markdown (gfm) by using

```yaml
format: gfm
```

It should be possible to use the output with both Quarto and GitHub.

See also the [Quarto docs on gfm](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/markdown/gfm.html).

Comment: Thank you. All my googling did not surface this up. Need to spend more time on the quarto docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out GitHub's documentation on what syntax it supports for its Markdown engine, [Basic writing and formatting syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax), which though covers a lot of scenarios doesn't out-of-the-box support engines like the RStudio Quarto one you mention.

Another option you have is to use [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/), where you can generate a static site using tools like [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) and some custom plugins for your use case, to generate a static site and upload it.

I don't know off the top of my head specific plugins for RStudio Quarto, but I'd imagine you should be able to find one of the static site generator tools will support it. Hope this helps!